# Sum unique values based on another column

Tags: excel, pivot-table, distinct-values, unique-values

I have four values: *Name, Maturity, Hasinteracted?, SizeofName*

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Czc.png]

**Entity** (Constant) - represents the name of the entity.
**Maturity** (Variable) - In months, how long have they been active with us (i.e. 1 would be one month etc)
**Hasinteracted?** (True, False) - If yes, their value is TRUE
**SizeofEntity** (constant) - How large is this entity? This value varies for different Names but is constant for its' own name (i.e. Entity A will always be 12 regardless of their maturity, while Entity B will be 19 regardless of their maturity)

***What I am trying to do:***

Using a PivotTable, I have been able to create a table which has `Maturity` in the rows, and count of interactions for each maturity in the column.

The part that I am struggling with is the total `SizeofEntity`. Basically, I want it to sum the total `SizeofEntity`. The issue is that if Entity A repeats in the name section, it will double in this calculation.

***Example***

Entity A shows once (size = 12) in maturity 1 and maturity 2, Entity B shows once (size = 19) in maturity 1.

What I am hoping to see in the value section is the total SizeofEntity in Maturity 1 being `31` and `12` in Maturity 2, which occurs.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mbcr.png]

Now, if Entity A was to interact twice in Maturity 1, I would want the size to remain same, but the number of interactions to increase. With the way it is currently structured, because Entity A is repeated, the interaction now increases by one, but so does the size of the entity (from `31` to `43`).

Is there a way to have Excel ignore the value in the `SizeofEntity` if the Entity name is repeated in another column, or is there another way to make this possible?

The data provided in the images is a small example. I am dealing with a much larger dataset with over 300 different names with hundreds of interactions per maturity period.

Comment: The correct images should now be up. I am using Excel 2013 at the moment. I could give that a go. How would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've achieved your expected results using the following logic.

Create a column called EntityConcat on column E. With this you can detect if you have duplicate entity and maturity pairs. 
I've concatented them using this formula then dragged down:

> =A2&B2

In another column (F) detect if they repeat and only flag the first occurence:

> =IF(COUNTIF(E$2:E2,E2)=1,1,"")

Finaly I've created another column that shows sizes for the first occurence only:

> =IF(F2=1,D2,0)

Now on your pivot table you can count "SizeofEntity" for total number of occurences but should instead sum this last column's values, where no duplicate entity sizes will be found.

Hope this is what you were after.

Comment: Dekimasu! Thank you for your help on the matter, I really do appreciate it. Can I ask how you came to the solution? Was it previous experience or trial and error?

Comment: I have encountered similar problems before so roughly knew how to approach this. It was a case of breaking down the problem into smaller chunks. Glad I could help!